# What's the running time of computing the size of subtree of every node in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

When I was doing a binary tree exercise, I had one question that confused me:

Given a binary tree (via a pointer to its root) with n nodes. Let size(n) denote the number of nodes in the subtree rooted at the node n. What is the necessary and sufficient time to compute size(n) for every node n of the tree?

Can anyone give me some hints on the above question? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What were your thoughts?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, hi, sorry I didn't include my own thoughts in the post...I think in order to compute the size of a node's subtree, we may iteratively do that-we continue to traverse the tree from the root, and until we reach the leaf, we add 1 and return. So that means each node will be reached through O(logn) time, and since we need to compute every node's substree, so that would be O(nlogn). I'm sure if my thoughts are correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can have O(n) space then you can have a O(n) solution:

Here 'num' is the reason of the O(n) space.

```
struct tree
{
    int num;
    struct tree *l;
    struct tree *r;
};

void sizeofnode(tree *node)
{
    if (!node) {
        return;
    }
    node->num = 0;

    if (node->l) {
        node->num += node->l->num; // size of left subtree
    }

    if (node->r) {
        node->num += node->r->num; // size of right subtree
    }

    node->num ++; // this is to add the size of the root of the subtree

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple errors in @user1952500 algorithm:

1. return 0 inside a void function
2. adds to node->num without giving an initial value
3. Doesn't traverse child nodes to calculate subtree size

So a fixed version would be:

```
struct tree
{
    int num;
    struct tree *l;
    struct tree *r;
};

void sizeofnode(tree *node)
{
    if (node) { 
        node->num = 1; // Our size

        if (node->l) {
            sizeofnode(node->l);       // Calculates size of left subtree
            node->num += node->l->num; // Adds size of left subtree
        }

        if (node->r) {
            sizeofnode(node->r);       // Calculates size of right subtree
            node->num += node->r->num; // Adds size of right subtree
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the size of the the subtree rooted at n, you will have to recursively get size of each subtree. This essentially means that you end up visiting each node of the tree.

So I believe that the time compexity is O(n).

Comment: hi! Getting the size of the subtree of the root is not enough, I think the question is asking the running time of getting EVERY node's subtree size.

Comment: @DanQing: But as smk points out, you have to do that as part of getting the size of the whole tree.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, so does that mean that to get the subtree size of every node in the tree, we actually need O(n*n) time?

Comment: @DanQing: No.  Because in order to get the size of subtree A, you must already have found the size of subtree A->left and subtree A->right.  And this applies for any A, including the root of the tree.  And we know that we can find the size of the entire tree in O(n).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, you're right. I totally skipped the beauty of recursion...Thanks!